# How to get sql error in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server 2005. I created a stored procedure which works most of the time, but I found an instance of where it doesn't do what I want.

Currently, the code does something like this

```
if @@error <> 0
  begin
   select @message_error = "There was a database error adding product "+ @product + " to product line
  end
```

Where `@message_error` is an output variable.

So, I can `select @@error` and get a number, but all I really want is the SQL error.

Something like *Hey, I couldn't do this because there is a fk constraint on this column* or whatever. I found this article on msdn
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592(v=sql.90).aspx

But it only goes over throwing custom exceptions with `RAISERROR`, I don't want to create my own error message or exception, I just want to know why stuff isn't working. I can execute the stored procedure through Management Studio and see the exact SQL error, but this is tedious trying to match data from the site and manually inserting it that way.

How do I get the SQL error text into an output variable?

Comment: Have you looked at ERROR_MESSAGE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's part of a stored procedure template I use:

```
/*  CREATE PROCEDURE...  */

DECLARE
  @ErrorMessage   varchar(2000)
 ,@ErrorSeverity  tinyint
 ,@ErrorState     tinyint

/*  Additional code  */

BEGIN TRY

/*  Your code here  */

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    SET @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)

    BREAK
END CATCH

/*  Further cleanup code  */
```

Try/Catch blocks can be tricky but are much more thorough than @@error. More importantly, you can use the various error_xxx() functions within them. Here, I store the proper error message in variable @ErrorMessage, along with enough other data to re-raise the error. From here, any number of options are available; you could make @ErrorMessage an output variable, test for and handle specific errors, or build your own error messages (or adjust the existing ones to be clearer--you may get irritated finding out how often you'll want to do that). Other options will present themsleves.

Something to look out for: in some situations, SQL will throw two error messages back to back... and `error_message()` will only catch the last one, which usually says something like "attempt to create object failed", with the real error given in the first error message. This is where building your own error message comes in.

Comment: This is a really great answer, and I can't believe I overlooked it when I originally accepted an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I call `Error_Message()` on a other server but its get NULL !!? Have any way to catch errors on server A by a Sp on server B. in this model when a error raised on server A, in Catch block of server A call a SP from server B.  but that not work ! why ?

Comment: @Khosravifar, that is a complex enough issue that you really should post it as its own question--and add a link to it here as a comment.

Answer (score 12):

You could use a general Try/Catch and then construct more details about the error within the CATCH section e.g.

```
DECLARE @DetailedErrorDesc VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN TRY

--tsql code goes here

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

SELECT @DetailedErrorDesc =         
  CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR) + ' : '+
  CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR) + ' : ' +
  CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR) + ' : ' +
  ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ' : ' +
  ERROR_MESSAGE() + ' : ' +
  CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR);

--Now you can decide what to do with the detailed error message....return it or log it etc

END CATCH
```

Answer (score 3):

use try ... catch and in catch block you can use ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_NUMBER() functions