# Update check t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi have procedure where update table.

```
UPDATE myTbl
SET pswd = @newPswd
where id = @id and pswd = @pswd
```

now want check

```
if pswd <> @pswd
print 'error'
```

how do it ? when i write it after where have an error invalid  column

Comment: No, we don't check the contents of the table to see whether the update succeeded. If the update failed, there will have been an error. In a T/SQL procedure, errors used to be checked by looking at @@error, but now Try/Catch is available, and is much better. [See this example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647437/how-to-get-sql-error-in-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call the name of the column directly in an if statement. You'll need to set the value of pswd to a local variable (different from the @pswd variable), and then compare the two.

```
 Declare @tempPswd varchar(20)
Select @tempPswd = pswd
From myTbl
Where id = @id

if (@tempPswd <> @pswd)
  Print 'Error....'
Else
Begin
  Update myTbl
  Set pswd = @newPswd
  Where id = @id and pswd = @pswd
End
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`@@ROWCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ms187316%28v=sql.110%29.ASPX) to work out how many rows the immediate previous statement affected:

```
UPDATE myTbl
SET pswd = @newPswd
where id = @id and pswd = @pswd
if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    print 'Error - @id and/or @pswd didn''t match'
```

You might want to also consider using [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ms178592.aspx) or [`THROW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ee677615.aspx) (if appropriate) rather than just `PRINT` for error conditions.

If you need to do further work with the specific row count that's returned, you ought to capture it in a variable and work with that - *every* statement causes `@@ROWCOUNT` to reset.

Comment: in if pswd <> @pswd i mean for examlpe if pswd = 5  and @ psw = 6   if 5<>6  print 'error'

Comment: @GeoVIP - I'm taking a different tack to deduce that the @pswd didn't match the current password - if the `UPDATE` affects zero rows, then obviously one or both of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause wasn't met. If your `@id` values are guaranteed to match one particular row's `id` column, then you can *deduce* that `pswd` and `@pswd` didn't match.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `EXISTS()` function

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTbl WHERE id = @id and pswd <> @pswd)
BEGIN
    print 'error'
END
```