# VBScript using stored procedures not working when introducing new column

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, asp-classic, vbscript, adodb

I'm working on a desktop-application, database, webserver-access combination which someone wrote some years ago. My task is to do some optimications/refactoring and to introduce new features to this application(s). I have not much experience in developing web applications, so it's quite difficult for me to find a solution to my problem described below, hoping someone can help me.

The webapplication is written with ASP and VBScript having some small javascript functions which do not affect my question. It uses ADODB for communicating with the database.

The database is a MS-SQLserver 2008 database.

The desktop-application is written in C++/CLI using the .Net built-in features for communicating with the database. With this application everything is working.

For introducing some features I need to add new columns to tables in the database. Inserting and updating of the main table is done with stored procedures. I added a column named "internal" of type "bit":

```
    ALTER TABLE maintable
    ADD internal bit
    GO
```

I altered the stored procedures for inserting and updating, just by adding the internal column and a parameter for it. I made only these changes:

- 1x line for the parameter
- added internal in the column and values list for the insert
- added setting internal column with parameter for the update

In the vbscript which already was working before any changes I added the code for appending the value for internal as new parameter (its the same for insert & update):

```
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Append(sqlcmd.CreateParameter("@internal",11,1))
    sqlcmd.Parameters("@internal")=0
```

After these changes the update und insert procedures of the vbscript stopped working. I tried several datatypes for the parameter and also changing the column (different name, different datatype). Nothing worked. The stored procedures themself are working fine when executed directly in the database and also when used by the desktop-application.
I started to debug everything with printing some debuginformations ect. I added try/catch in the stored procedures and a outparameter to get some errors according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13647654/2724509) answer and I selected all input-parameters into a varchar outparameter. This caused the next strange results.
While updating "worked" (because the stored procedure didn't cause a database error and I got the input-parameter informations which didn't show wrong values, but no update was performed) inserting didn't workin any way. My tracing outputs where printed till the `sqlcmd.Execute`, this line seems to crash since the trace outputs after this line wheren't printed. As long as I did not use the outparameter the insert itself didn't work, but all trace outputs got printed. I tried to retrieve information about a possible database error directly after the execution of the code with:

```
    DECLARE @ErrorVariable INT;

    SET @ErrorVariable = @@ERROR;
    SELECT @ErrorVariable AS ErrorID,
        text
        FROM sys.messages
        WHERE message_id = @ErrorVariable;
    GO
```

There was no database error.

Everything works fine from the desktop-application side. As mentioned the stored procedures executed directly in the database will work properly. I suppose the the error is somewhere in web-scripting-stuff. So now here are the concrete questions:

1. Why would the stored procedure not work (properly) when adding a new column to the database (it is there) and no syntax errors in the stored procedures or vbscript?
2. Why the `sqlcmd.Execute` stops working when adding a outparameter to the insert stored procedure? The try-block in the stored procedures includes everything between "AS BEGIN" and "END" having the catch-block directly before "END". Syntax is here also correct.

Answer (score 1):

try to catch the error at the asp end.

```
On Error Resume Next
sqlcmd.Execute

for each objerr in yourconnection.Errors
    Response.write objerr.Description & "<br/>"
next

On Error GoTo 0
```

Please check this link:

[ADO Connection Object Errors Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Since I've asked this question I had no chance to try your hint, because I had more important tasks to solve. Now I'm leaving the work here, which means that I will not be able to track down the problem. Your answer seems to me as helpful for solving the problem, so I will you give finally a upvote :)