# return ERROR_MESSAGE() as output variable in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to return the ERROR_MESSAGE() in a variable, but this is not working because is like raising the error but I don't want it like that. I want to receive the return value (0 ok, 1 error), plus the id of the insert in the variable @Id and the error msg in this variable @ErrorMsg if there is an error

Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cimpl].[TestInsert]
(
    @TestId INT,
    @Name NVARCHAR(50), 
    @Id INT OUTPUT,
    @ErrorMsg NVARCHAR(4000) = NULL OUTPUT 
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ReturnVal int

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @ReturnVal = 0;
    SET @ErrorMsg = '';

    BEGIN TRY

        -- Insert statement
        INSERT [dbo].[Test]
                (
                  [TestId],
                  [Name]
                )
        VALUES  (
                  @TestId, 
                  @Name,                  
                )

        SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ReturnVal = 1;
        SET @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH

    RETURN @ReturnVal;

END
```

Here is the call:

```
DECLARE @IdIns INT
DECLARE @ErrorM NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT = 0

EXEC @ReturnValue = 
    [cimpl].[TransactInsert]
        @TestId= 'ee', --I'm forcing the error
        @Name = 'A', 
        @Id = @IdIns OUTPUT,
        @ErrorMsg = @ErrorM OUTPUT

SELECT @ErrorM
SELECT @ReturnValue
SELECT @IdIns
```

Comment: Have you seen the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647437/how-to-get-sql-error-in-stored-procedure

Comment: I don't like that approach, is there any other way? I don't want to raise an error, I just want to get the error message as output